# docker: 'stack' is not a docker command

Tags: docker

I'm trying to follow the tutorial https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#run-your-new-load-balanced-app, but if I try to run the command

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab
```

I get the error message

```
docker: 'stack' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'.
```

Why is this command not working? (My Docker version is `1.12.3, build 6b644ec`).

Comment: my guess is the docker version.  my `$ docker -v` returns `Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e` and `$ docker stack --help` returns successfully

Comment: this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your Docker version. Option for using `docker-compose.yml` with `docker stack deploy` was added in version 1.13.0.